# Declare delegate type to match method signature

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Is there a way to declare a delegate type that matches a given function? That is, I don't want to copy and paste the parameters and have to remember to update the delegate any time to the function signature changes. Ideally, something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    void APIFunction();
}

delegate APIDel = Foo.APIFunction;
```

To allow me to do this:

```
function IntPtr GetAPIFunctionPointer ()
{
    var foo = new Foo();

    APIDel del = foo.APIFunction
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(del);
    return del;
}
```

For context, I have a plugin based application that supports both managed and unmanaged plugins. The plugin API is declared with a set of C function pointers. There is a managed interface with methods that mirror the C API. For managed plugins I implement the interface, create delegates to the interface methods, and marshal those delegates into function pointers that the native side can call. I'm trying to eliminate the manual delegate declaration because that makes 3 places I have to manually update function parameters.

Comment: I think best you can do is use T4 templates to autogenerate that boilerplate code for you (just delegate types, or whole thing).

Comment: Good tip. Since I'm using C++/CLI I can go one simpler and use a preprocessor macro. I'm still looking for a non-macro solution though.

Comment: In C++/CLI, you might be able to use a template to extract the type automatically.  Or perhaps even `decltype`.